# Android ToolBar Menu Item not Clickable

Tags: android, android-toolbar

My android app menu item is not clickable I Add `app:showAsAction="always"` and  `android:enabled="true"` to the menu item and The Item Button is shown but it's not clickable, What Im missing here ?

App Theme :  parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"

Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Settings.ReportTable">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/balance_table_SV"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity :

```
public class ReportTable extends AppCompatActivity {

    ScrollView balance_table_SV;
    TableLayout tableLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report_table);
     
         Toolbar toolbar =  findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
         toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.excel);
        balance_table_SV = findViewById(R.id.balance_table_SV);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.excel, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        if(item.getItemId() == R.menu.excel) {
            export_to_excel();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it looks like you're comparing the item ID to the resource ID of the entire menu (`R.menu.excel`). You should have an ID for each menu item to use for click handling:

```
<item android:id="@+id/excel" />
```

```
if(item.getItemId() == R.id.excel) { ... }
```

---

Secondly there seems to be quite a bit of confusion here between the `Toolbar` and the Android action bar. You are you using a mixture of both in the code you have provided which is causing the inconsistency.

Firstly, if you're using a `Toolbar` in your layout, you don't need the action bar at all, therefore you should be inheriting from a `NoActionBar` Material Components theme (such as `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar`). Then in order to setup your `Toolbar` you have two options:

### Set the `Toolbar` as the action bar

With this approach you can register the `Toolbar` to act as the action bar for an activity, which means it correctly triggers the `onOptionsItemSelected` callback etc. So to do this we need to register it in `onCreate`:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Then you should probably be using `onCreateOptionsMenu` to inflate the menu instead of `Toolbar.inflateMenu` just as you've already done in your code:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.excel, menu);
```

And finally to listen for menu item clicks, you can override `onOptionsItemSelected` and check the item ID as I outlined above.

### Setup the `Toolbar` independently

Instead of registering the `Toolbar` as the action bar, you can instead just use the `Toolbar` like any regular view and set it up directly. Firstly to inflate the menu you can call:

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.excel);
```

Then in order to listen for click events you can attach an `OnMenuItemClickListener` as follows:

```
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

        ...
    }
});
```

---

Both approaches are valid but I personally prefer the second. It seems strange to try and work around the activity lifecycle when you could just treat the `Toolbar` normally.

Comment: Thanks fro your answer, I'v changed it to the item id but still not clickable

Comment: Is `onOptionsItemSelected` getting called?

Comment: No its not called !

Comment: Edited my answer with some more detailed explanation.